# Cumulative sum of last 5 rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, where-clause, partition

I have a question with regards to a SQL query. 
I need to calculate a cumulative running total of the last 5 rows of values in column X based on the values in column Y.  Column Y could contain Yes,No or Maybe

Data example would be:

```
   Date  Column X   Column Y   Yes cum total  No cum total Maybe Total

   31/8   1000      Y          1200           800          250
   30/8   500       N           250           800          250 
   29/8   200       Y           250           375          250
   28/8   300       N            50           375          250
   27/8   250       M            50            75          250
   26/8    50       Y            50            75           0 
   25/8    75       N            0             75           0
```

I have tried case and partition but in each case when I specify the where part it does not give me the cumulative value but only the totals of the values where the where condition is true.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[Data table and required results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajgot.png)

Comment: I added an image to show the layout of the data better.  I am using sql server 2016.  Thanks!

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas For each row in the table I need to show a sum of the current and 4 previous rows of column X based on the values in column Y.  So column Y contains Y="Yes", N='No" and M="Maybe" .  In the example I gave the 1200 total in "Yes cum total" is the 1000 on 31/8 plus the 200 on 29/8.  The 800 total on 31/8 show in the "No cum total" is based on the 30/8 500 plus the 28/8 300.    Hope this helps to make it clearer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use cumulative sums with `case` and a window clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when y = 'Y' then x else 0 end) over
           (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as y,
       sum(case when y = 'N' then x else 0 end) over
           (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as n,
       sum(case when y = 'M' then x else 0 end) over
           (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as m
from t;
```